# Performance metrics after downsampling

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a binary classification problem with an imbalanced dataset. I have decided to downsample the majority class and I’m wondering what the best approach is when calculating performance metrics on a model that has been trained on a downsampled dataset.

I noticed that the `sklearn.metrics.precision_score` and `sklearn.metrics.recal_score` functions have a `sample_weight` attribute. Is the purpose of this attribute to supply a weight for the downsampled class relative to the ratio in which I downsampled?

For example, if I had 1,000,000 samples for the negative class and I decided to downsample to 100,000, would I set the `sample_weight` attribute to be equal to 1,000,000 / 100,000 = 10 for the negative class?